# sudo - one user does not need to type password

Tags: centos, sudo

We are setting up a server with centos 6.10, when setting up a user with sudo, we discovered that sudo never asks for password. Setting up another user with the same (full) sudo rights, it is asked for password.

I have tried both to set up the users explicitely and to add it to the wheel group with the same behaviour. I have also set the password timeout to 0 with no changes.

```
[root@noaspare ~]# su mysql 
bash-4.1$ ls -l ls: 
cannot open directory.: Permission denied 
bash-4.1$ sudo ls -l
[sudo] password for mysql: (Ctrl-C)
bash-4.1$ exit 

[root@noaspare ~]# su ssi 
[ssi@noaspare /root]$ ls 
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied 

[ssi@noaspare /root]$ sudo ls 
anaconda-ks.cfg  install.log  install.log.syslog  rpmbuild
```

sudo -l for the ssi gives:

```
Matching Defaults entries for ssi on this host:
    requiretty, !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE 
INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", 
env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME >    LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET 
 XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin,
timestamp_timeout=0


User ssi may run the following commands on this host:

Sudoers entry:
RunAsUsers: ALL
Commands:
ALL
```

Any idea why this configuration does not ask for a password? The only difference I can see between the two users is their shell, but I cannot see why that should matter.

The only line specific to the user is

```
ssi       ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Comment: Look for a `NOPASSWD` entry in your sudoers file(s). You can then link that config entry to the user account which works without prompting for a password.

Comment: That was my first idea as well, but no trace of any NOPASSWD in the sudoers..

Comment: Okay. Just to be clear, you should also check for additional sudoers files added with `#include` or `#includedir`. Another thing to check is if the behaviour only occurs with `sudo -l` or `sudo -v`. If that's the case, you can check the `listpw` or `verifypw` option. See the [man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.0/sudoers.man.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the solution was simple and logical when we just found out what was the problem: The user had in some way no password defined (however that could happen). After setting a password for the user, sudo also worked as expected.